# How to figure out encryption given input and output text?

Tags: encryption

I need to figure out how some fields are being encrypted.  In my program, I can change the input text and see the encrypted output text.

For example, "Admin" results in "51@fnmk5gHT[^FX".

I tried doing one letter at a time to see the results, but combing letters didn't really mean combining the result of the encrypted text.  Any idea how to begin? Or even identify what is being done here?

Comment: Peter, this is called cryptanalysis. For well designed algorithms, it is effectively impossible. Your best bet is to look at source or even disassemble the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most software states what type of encryption they use, so it should be pretty easy to find out.
If that's not possible, you could try to encrypt the same string with the most common tools existing and see what matches the result.

Start with MD5 generator (http://www.md5calc.com) and go from there with the most common ones. All of them have only versions. Theres an extremely high chance that it is one of the most widely used ones.

Comment: I'll check this out now and report back!

Comment: Perhaps you mean http://www.md5calc.com/ ? The link you provided is a website for medical calculations.

Comment: Yes, ancient KB. Fixed.